# Web visualisations for data?

Tags: javascript, flash, visualization, data-visualization

I would like to display a bunch of data in a meaningful way through visualizations on a site.

I have been experimenting with **RaphaelJS** library, but **performance on IE8 is terrible**, and **HTML5 canvas** is still **not widely supported**.

So I'm left with **Flash** and any existing libraries.

On the flash side there seem to be many, but because of this I am a bit lost and don't have the possibility to experiment with each one.

---

( I will list any libraries that people have pointed out here. )

**Flash / Flex:**

- Flare
- Axiis
- BirdEye
- Flex Charting Components
- Core Components/Charting
- IBM ILOG Elixir

  [Thanks ZackBeNimble (link to answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119357/web-visualisations-for-data/2119775#2119775)

**Javascript:**

- Google Visualizations API Gallery

  [Thanks Justin Johnson (link to answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119357/web-visualisations-for-data/2119634#2119634)
- Google ExplorerCanvas (HTML5 Canvas for IE)

  [Thanks Craig Stuntz (link to answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119357/web-visualisations-for-data/2119428#2119428)
- ProcessingJS

  [Thanks Bobby (link to answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119357/web-visualisations-for-data/2119373#2119373)

**Java:**

- IBM's many-eyes.com

  [Thanks Richard Inglis (link to answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119357/web-visualisations-for-data/2121173#2121173)

---

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do end up going with Flash, consider the following visualization libraries.  My personal favorite is Flare, but the Flex Charting Components probably have the easiest learning curve.

- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) - Open source, pure Actionscript - [Demos](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo)
- [Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) - Open source, Flex + Degrafa - [Demos](http://www.axiis.org/examples.html)
- [BirdEye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/) - Open source, Flex oriented - [Demos](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/branches/ng/examples/demo/BirdEyeExplorer.html)
- [Flex Charting Components](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_intro_3.html#223770) - Proprietary, Flex - [Demos under Flex Core Components/Charting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/)
- [IBM ILOG Elixir](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/visualization/elixir/about/?S_CMP=wspace) - Proprietary, pretty, Flex [Demos under Data Visualization/IBM ILOG Elixir](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/)

Comment: Thank you for listing these!! :D With the demos, that is really great!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [Google Visualizations API Gallery](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html) (which are different from its graphing API).  It's a collection of different, cross-browser visualizations. Some are in flash, others render static images.  Also, some integrate with GWT.

[image]
[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/images/icon-imageareachart.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/images/icon-areachart.png))</sub>

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Google visualisations really does look good.

Answer (score 2):

Why not Processing or ProcessingJS?

http://processing.org/

http://processingjs.org/

Comment: **IE is not supported!**

From processingjs.org website
 
"Processing.js is explicitly developed for browsers that support the HTML5 <Canvas> element."

Comment: here's a processing implementation in silverlight http://paulirish.com/work/canvasShims/

Answer (score 1):

We use [Google ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) for IE support and then a canvas-based plot library. I've not exhaustively examine the performance, but it works well enough for us in IE 8.

Comment: I'm afraid it uses VML like RaphaelJS does, performance of which on IE8 is sluggish.

Comment: Here's a test, which seems OK to me in IE 8. http://excanvas.freehostia.com/callout-speech-bubble-excanvas-example.html Your needs may be different, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are some fine-looking visualisations at [many-eyes.com](http://www.many-eyes.com/) - which I think is run by IBM. I don't know what they're using though: some kind of Java Applet...

Comment: Thanks. They look good, but I'm really scared of using Java on a web page! 30% of my users have no Java installed too.

Comment: I suspect they are using Prefuse (http://prefuse.org) and/or their own home grown software.  Flare which was mentioned above is the next generation of Prefuse.

Answer (score 1):

How about Tableau?  [Tableau Public](http://www.tableaupublic.com) (or Tableau Server for private sites) provides a quick and flexible tool for building data visualizations that can be embedded without any plugins.  It won't give you full programmatic control though - it's designed for analysts.