# Flash relationship map

Tags: flash, visualization, force-based-algorithm

Does anyone know any Flash fla's which are out there and free which do something similar to http://audiomap.tuneglue.net/ (you have to type in a search term to see it in action).

What I'm after is the flash to create the node in the middle which expands out into children and then each of those children can be expanded out into more children, etc. while keeping their distance from one another so as to not overlap.  I'd like it so that if you clicked on a node to expand it, it would shoot off to a web site and get an xml feed which could then be used to create the children.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is called a *[force-directed radial tree graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms)*. Here are a few highlights from google:

1. You might be able to adapt something from [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org) (see [Demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo)->Layouts->Force and Layouts->Radial for examples that nearly do what you want).
2. [Birdeye](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ravis/RaVisExamples/example-binaries/RaVisExplorer.html#), in particular the RaVis Explorer (Flex component).
3. Have a look at [spicynodes](http://www.spicynodes.org/index.html) - its proprietary flash code, but there's a free version for individual use.
4. There's a free but less pretty version which is part of the [OpenLaszlo](http://openlaszlo-coder.blogspot.com/2009/12/force-directed-graph-using-openlaszlo.html) framework.
5. There's also [Constellation](http://asterisq.com/), but it's a $550 license, so not much use if you're looking for something free :)

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119357/web-visualisations-for-data), which was about flash visualisation in general.

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction anyway.

Answer (score 2):

@Richard Inglis has already mentioned [Prefuse Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) which provides some nice flash based layouts. I'm not sure if it can do on-demand loading of data into a graph that its showing though.

One, **non-flash** suggestion I have is the [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/). You can do on-demand data loading with the visualization components in JIT. Its just a suggestion since I'm assuming your looking to do this in a web based application.